# Do daily quota replenishment and cron task use the same timezone?

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, timezone

I've scheduled daily job to be informed about daily quota replenishment, which happens [*at midnight Pacific time*](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#How_Resources_are_Replenished). Looks like it is equal to UTC-7 (or GMT-7). My local time is GMT+4.
When checking the log (GMT+4 is chosen there), I see that my job runs at midnight:

```
2014-04-22 04:00:00.278 /admin/resetquota 200 121ms 0kb AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) module=default version=1
```

But when now I check Quota Details page of GAE console (local time is 5:26pm), it says that quotas will be reset in next 18 hours, i.e. at 11am local time.

Does it mean that cron tasks use UTC time, when quota replenishment happens at UTC-7? Looks like cron.yaml [allows to define timezone](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron#Python_app_yaml_About_cron_yaml). How can I indicate the UTC-7 here? Is it `US/Pacific`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes cron tasks use UTC time by default, but you can specify a timezone and **US/Pacific** is valid:

```
- description: daily task
  url: /cron/daily
  schedule: every day 00:00
  timezone: US/Pacific
```

If you try and use a timezone that is not recognised, when you update_cron an error is thrown:

```
Error parsing yaml file:
Unable to assign value 'US/does-not-exist' to attribute 'timezone':
timezone 'US/does-not-exist' is unknown
  in "./cron.yaml", line 13, column 13
```